# How to persist the user_token obtained from a provider with HWIOAuthBundle?

Tags: symfony, oauth, hwioauthbundle

After installing HWIOauthBundle and successfully going through the OAuth process for Github, I find myself lost.

Here is the problem: I need to have the user token persisted so that I can use it more than once without asking the user to go through the process again. 
I'm not sure if it is possible to use HWIOAuthBundle to accomplish this or if I need to implement a custom service for this purpose.

May be HWIOAuthBundle fires an event when it gets the data from the provider, so I can just hook up a listener and persist it. 
Please, if someone has done this or have any idea of the best way to get this done, answer this.

I appreciate you taking time to read this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the aswer here: https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697 though I changed drastically the logic to meet my particular requirements.

I'm able to get the token for the user and persist it without problems.